# about repositoryItemCheckEdit

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I've added `repositoryItemCheckEdit` in a `xtragrid control's column`. And i'm having total 3 columns in my xtragridview. From which two columns will be filled with the help of fields from my table when i'm setting datasource property of gridcontrol.

problem which is i'm facing is that when i'm changing the status of checkbox from xtragrid to checked for one time it works but when i'm checking from next row that time the previous selection of checkbox from gridview lost. It only maintain for only one row. and i want it two remain for multiple row.

how to do this?

my datatable contains two fields as TemplateTitle  & TemplateBody. And my xtragrid contains three columns as two from datatable & additional column as a repositoryItemCheckEdit which is unbound column. I created columns of gridview at design time. and i've set just datasource property of gridcontrol to datatable.

thanks.

Comment: Provide more info. What's your data source structure? Could you provide a piece of code reproducing this?

Comment: I think this has to do with the update/validation of focused row when focus moves away and or in combination with the way you bind the data, XtraGrid and repositoryEditors work very fine if we know how to use them.

Comment: @ Davide Piras : What should i do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the repositoryItemCheckEdit is unbound you have to control the CheckEdit's checked state manually using the grid's CustomUnboundColumnData event otherwise the state is lost when you move to a different row.

You must search DevExpress support center for these type of issues. These are pretty well documented and can be found easily there.

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/B135631.aspx
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q254784.aspx

Comment: The suggestions on the DevExpress support center are just false workarounds. The Problem arises by using wrong collection type for binding. Just use a WinForms BindingList instead (and not the WPF-Collections not appropriate) will fix the problem at its root and is not just a lousy workaround.

Comment: The column is unbound so, it will not update even if you use BindingList.

Comment: The false binding on the other columns will prevent the unbound column even from updating manually - had this, solved it! so thx for voting me down... will provide less and less answers to SO because of people like you voting down correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

Using BindingList and not DataTable or ObservableCollection solves the problem for booleans bound to a checkbox in a (DevExpress) GridView/GridControl ( Windows Forms ).

Comment: The column is unbound.

Comment: The column is bound! Citation: "i've set just datasource property of gridcontrol to datatable" - so the DataSource is actually bound to a DataTable and not unbound. A single column can not be unbound and the callback does not happen if no BindingList is used.